# Make 65-57=91 correct by moving one matchstick

Tags: riddle, matches

65 - 57 = 91

Not sure how to make this correct by only moving one matchstick.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 8):

You need to:

> Move the 7's top matchstick down to make a sort of mirrored L, then turn the whole thing upside down, and you get 16 = 75 - 59, which is correct!

Answer (score 6):

You can

> move the lower half of the 1 to the left 5 to make a 6:
>  
>  66-57=9<sup>1</sup>

Comment: wow. +1. now THAT is thinking outside the box. I love it!